# Bootstrap grid columns does not seem to be working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I have set up this grid for my webpage:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
         <div class="top-nav">
              <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-1">
                        <img src="https://sitename.com/logo.jpg">
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-7 mid-nav">
                        <!-- Search box & Navbar comes here -->
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-1" style="margin-top:30px !important;">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-4x sabad-kharid"></i></a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-3">
                        <form method="POST" action="">
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                               <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                           </div>
                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                  </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And the result is shown in this:

[image]

As you can see the Bootstrap form does not appear in the `col-3` class and it appears at the below of this row. However it should be placed at the left side in the div with class of `col-3`.

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `col-xs-1` `col-xs-7` `col-xs-3` in your class (instead `col-7`) or any size and display what you want.

Comment: Greate. Is that necessary to include `col-md-7` and `col-lg-7` as well when using `col-xs-7` ?

Comment: No. If you use `xs` that means for xs size and bigger size! so this style add for `md` size and `lg` size and so on.

Comment: be careful if you set `class="col-xs-1 col-md-5"`. this means xs=1,  sm=1, md=5, lg=5